# Is there a max number of answers per day

Tags: discussion, feature-request, rate-limiting

The question pretty much says it all, Is there a max number of answers per day. While I'm at it is there a max number of questions.

If there isn't does anyone think it should be implemented.

Comment: @KateGregory thanks that answer is actually really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give as much answers as you like per day.

But you will only get max 200 rep from upvotes a day. After you reach that limit (called *rep-cap*) you will only get more rep for accepts and bounties.

Comment: upvotes on questions and answers, and also do you think that we should have a limit to either

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that comment. Can you please rephrase that.

Comment: Sorry it's really two questions. By upvotes did you mean both those on questions and answers. And the second part do you think we should have a limit to either. Also it looks like the dupe actually has the answers I want

Comment: Yes, I meant you can only have 200 rep from upvotes of both - questions and answers. And since there is already a limit to both in combination - I think it is just fine the way it is. The limit is there so people will hopefully return to the real life after hitting the rep cap.

Comment: That only helps smart people return to there real lives ;)

Comment: @juergend Are you sure about the 200 rep per day?  I got over 200 today only from answering.  Or are there loopholes, like, for example, a decent amount of that rep was from a question that I answered a few days ago.

Comment: @SteveP.: You got only 190 rep from upvotes. And 30 rep from accepts. These count extra.